# Using SSL with IIS Express

Tags: iis-express

I am trying to run my VS project on localhost using a fake domain (bobby.fisher.com).  To do this I created a virtual directory in the applicationhost.config file as follows:

```
 <site name="Tidywork.Integrations.Web" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\bobbyfisher\Workspaces\bobbyfisher.Integrations\bobbyfisher.Integrations\bobbyfisher.Integrations.Web" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:35464:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:bobby.fisher.com" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44321:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44321:bobby.fisher.com" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
```

However, when I tried run the program (https://bobby.fisher.com/) I ended up with an error:

```
This site can’t be reached
bobby.fisher.com refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Run SSL Diagnostics of Jexus Manager, https://jexusmanager.com

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a port in your URL when accessing the site, then if you chose `https://` (as per your example) the browser will try to connect on port 443 automatically - because that's the standard port for HTTPS.

But you haven't configured that port in your IIS settings. So either bind that port to https for your application, or use a port number explicitly in your URL (e.g. `https://bobby.fisher.com:44321`)

Comment: If I try as you have suggested, this is the error I get:  `Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from bobby.fisher.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: @user1124937 that's to be expected, and not really a problem - it's just because your SSL certificate is self-signed and not verified by a 3rd party (you paid for a certificate for a real site it would be verified and the browser would be able to trust it automatically). It does indicate that the connection is working though. If there's an option to ignore that problem and proceed, you can safely do so since you know it's your local server. Is it really essential to serve your local site over HTTPS though? You've got a regular HTTP binding there as well which you could use.

Comment: @user1124937 P.S. If my answer has helped you, which it seems it has, please remember to mark it as "accepted" and/or upvote - thanks :-)